# jQuery Mobile - Clearing all pages and adding new ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am dynamically generating pages and adding them to the page container (this part works).

I want to be able to clear of all the pages (empty the array) and re-add a new, dynamically generated list of pages.

I have tried:

```
    $(document).find('div[data-role="page"]').remove();
    $.mobile.pageContainer.empty();
```

Both of these calls remove the pages from the DOM, and I am able to re-add new pages, but when I attempt to call:

`jQ.mobile.changePage(page1);`

I am receiving the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_trigger' of undefined
```

On the line (in jQuery mobile):

```
fromPage.data( "mobile-page" )._trigger( "beforehide", null, { nextPage: toPage } );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you dynamically load in new page content, and you removing (and readding) the element `fromPage`, which you are using trigger on? If so, the event binding is going to be lost

Comment: I don't find anything related to `jquery-ui` hence removing the tag, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There are better ways to remove pages. It depends on when you want to remove them. They can be removed once hidden.

Comment: @elzi I am not sure if I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Omar I want to generate a bunch of pages, add them all, and then at some point, delete them all, and add an entirely new set of pages. What is the better way of doing so?

Comment: Easiest way is to give all dynamic pages a class to access them easily. But there should be one page in DOM, you can't leave page container empty. Active page shouldn't be removed, that's why you got an error.

Comment: So, if I wanted to remove all the pages, I would 1) add a placeholder page 2) set the active page to the placeholder page 3) remove all of the other pages 4) set the active page to a normal page. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Assuming you have pages p1, p2, p3 and p4 is active, and you want to remove all pages including p4. (1) remove p 1-3 (2) navigate to new page e.g. p5 (3) remove p4 when it's hidden.

Comment: When you say hidden, do you mean manually hidden? i.e. $elem.hide()? To remove pages, do I simply delete the div?

Comment: No, hidden means you moved to another page. To remove pages, yes simply `.remove()`. But this doesn't mean that they're removed from browser's navigation history nor are they removed from jQM navigation history.